# How we access google fonts through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get all available fonts from google font api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065542/get-all-available-fonts-from-google-font-api)

How we can retrieve the dynamic list of web fonts offered by the Google Web Fonts service through jquery or javascript?

Comment: highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065542/get-all-available-fonts-from-google-font-api

Comment: the precise answer from the question I've linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6997741/649687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Fontselect jQuery Plugin` available here:

https://github.com/tommoor/fontselect-jquery-plugin